# Why my styled component className logs reflect only final state?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Here is my styled components version
`"@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26"`

and I'll give you my example code.

```js
// index.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ProfileHomeContainer } from './styled';

const ProfileHome: React.FC = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const my = document.getElementById('test');
    console.log(my);
    console.log(test);
    setTest(true);
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <ProfileHomeContainer id='test' test={test ? 1 : 0}>
    </ProfileHomeContainer>
  )
}
```

```js
// styled.ts
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface ProfileHomeContainerProps {
  test: number;
}

const ProfileHomeContainer = styled.div<ProfileHomeContainerProps>`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 1101;
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.test ? '1' : '0')};
  transition: 1s;
`;
```

and There are two Global CSS classes for ProfileHomeContainer.

```css
// which has opacity: 0
.KBlzF{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-align-items:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-justify-content:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100vh;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);z-index:1101;opacity:0;-webkit-transition:1s;transition:1s;}


// has opacity: 1
.goFgwQ{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-align-items:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-justify-content:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100vh;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);z-index:1101;opacity:1;-webkit-transition:1s;transition:1s;}
```

and here is my console logs

```js
<div id="test" class="sc-crXcEl goFgwQ"> // result of console.log(my)
false // result of console.log(test)
<div id="test" class="sc-crXcEl goFgwQ">
true
```

Here is my question. Why my component rendered with goFgwQ first?
I think it should be like this.

```js
<div id="test" class="sc-crXcEl KBlzF">
false
<div id="test" class="sc-crXcEl goFgwQ">
true
```

Because, when useEffect run first time, I have `false` state value for test.

Here is my real code in github

[index.tsx](https://github.com/among-neighbors/AN-frontend/blob/main/client/src/components/organisms/ProfileHome/index.tsx)

[styled.ts](https://github.com/among-neighbors/AN-frontend/blob/main/client/src/components/organisms/ProfileHome/styled.ts)

Comment: Reference to whatever you query by `getElementById()` is not sustained between rerenders caused by state updates.

Comment: And, by the way, toggling visibility with `opacity` might not be a good idea from a performance standpoint as the contents of the corresponding DOM node (including children) is consuming main thread resources during render while not visible to the user.

Comment: Thank you for comments! By the way, I change `getElementById()` into `useRef()`, but console log result was same. I don't know why it occurs. @YevhenHorbunkov

Comment: and I read your second comment, but I handled that in parent component(Checker). So I think it's OK. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an "artifact" due to the `console.log` slight delay, and depending on its implementation, also worsened by its lazy access.

As you probably noticed, your `transition` does work, which means that your styled div (`<ProfileHomeContainer>`) did render first as opacity 0, then after at least an animation frame, was modified by the state change to get the other class version with opacity 1 (as expected from your `useEffect`).

The counter-intuitive part is that these 2 steps are not reflected by the `console.log(element)`, which display only the latter class name.

Here is a playground on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-surf-s1p4lt?file=/src/App.tsx

I intentionally delayed the transition to `test === true` to better see the effect of the browser console lazy access:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const my = document.getElementById("test");
    console.log(my);
    console.log(test);
    // Delayed toggling of test state
    setTimeout(() => setTest(true), 1000);
    //setTest(true);
  }, [test]);
```

Open *both* the CodeSandbox and the browser console's (they may have slightly different behaviour):

- Thanks to the delaying, we now have the 2 different class names correctly appearing in the console[image: initial log]
- In the *browser* console, now click to expand the element logged before the `false` log of test state value
- Its class name will *change* for the one with opacity 1! [image: log changed after expanding]
  (I am using Chrome browser)

This shows that the browser console displays objects in their state *when you expand them* (lazy access), which may differ from the moment you executed `console.log`, and even from the preview already displayed in the console!

Note that this effect does not play in CodeSandbox console: its implementation is slightly different.

Now to come back to your original issue, let's remove the delay (`setTimeout`).

We get back the original behaviour: all element logs display only the "final" class name (with opacity 1). This is very probably because by the time the `console.log` accesses the element to display its information, React already performed a new rendering pass (due to the `setTest(true)` in the `useEffect`).

This shows BTW that this element is actually the *same* between re-renders: React does a good job at re-using DOM elements.

We can see this last effect by *forcing* React to use a *different* DOM element, e.g. by specifying a [changing `key` prop](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop):

```
<ProfileHomeContainer id="test" test={test ? 1 : 0} key={test.toString()}>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-parm-mwgs9t?file=/src/App.tsx

Because the value passed to the `key` prop changes, React no longer re-uses the DOM element, but creates a *new* element, and the log is now as expected:
[image: logs with changing DOM elements because of key prop]

But this also breaks the `transition` effect, which must be applied on the *same* element to work.